# Using file path from GUI textbox in code in python

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, tkinter, filepath

I have a block of code that reads and writes to csv.
The reader takes a file "x" compares it to file "y" and returns new file "z"

Now I wrote a GUI program using tkinter that returns a filepath to a textbox in the GUI program.

The filepath I get as follows:

```
def OnButtonClick1(self):
    self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get())
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)
    filename = askopenfilename()
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for file in f:
            data = f.read()
            self.entry.insert(0,filename)
```

How can I use this filepath above in my reader to represent "myfile" in the code below?

```
    #Opening my enquiry list .cvs file
    datafile = open('myfile', 'r')
    datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
    n1 = []
    for row in datareader:
        n1.append(row)

        n = list(itertools.chain(*n1))
    print()
```

Help much appriciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
class gui:
...
    def OnButtonClick1(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)
        filename = askopenfilename()
        self.filename = filename
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for file in f:
            data = f.read()
            self.entry.insert(0,filename)
    def GetFilename(self):
        return self.filename
...
gui_object = gui()
...
#Opening my enquiry list .cvs file
myfile = gui_object.GetFilename()
datafile = open(myfile, 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
n1 = []
for row in datareader:
n1.append(row)

n = list(itertools.chain(*n1))
```